# Plupload and PHP post variables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post, plupload

I have a plupload script set up on a a webpage, and at the moment when you upload the files they are saved to the correct directory, but when you submit the form that the uploader is contained in, it passes the POST variables to a simple dump script.

The output from this script is:

```
uploader_0_tmpname  p180vem99v11u6e517hcqolbj14.jpg
uploader_0_name Test1.jpg
uploader_0_status   done
uploader_1_tmpname  p180vfjm2p12uoumicd71qica544.jpg
uploader_1_name Test2.jpg
uploader_1_status   done
```

Is it possible to pass the data as an array like `UploadedImages` and then the data can be like the following?

```
array(
    "0" => "p180vem99v11u6e517hcqolbj14.jpg",
    "1" => "p180vfjm2p12uoumicd71qica544.jpg",
)
```

If not, is it possible to create a php script to turn these variables into a usable array?

Comment: How do you access the output from the script? Are they stored in variables?

Comment: @AmalMurali from the upload script used by plupload or the script used when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery.plupload.queue.js file, search for and edit the following lines:

`l+='<input type="hidden" name="'+k+"_"+n+'_tmpname" value="'+plupload.xmlEncode(o.target_name)+'" />'`

to

`l+='<input type="hidden" name="'+k+"["+n+'][tmpname]" value="'+plupload.xmlEncode(o.target_name)+'" />'`

Now:

`l+='<input type="hidden" name="'+k+"_"+n+'_name" value="'+plupload.xmlEncode(o.name)+'" />'`

to

`l+='<input type="hidden" name="'+k+"["+n+'][name]" value="'+plupload.xmlEncode(o.name)+'" />'`

Finally:

`l+='<input type="hidden" name="'+k+"_"+n+'_status" value="'+(o.status==plupload.DONE?"done":"failed")+'" />'`

to

`l+='<input type="hidden" name="'+k+"["+n+'][status]" value="'+(o.status==plupload.DONE?"done":"failed")+'" />'`